# Ajax cache: false not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, google-chrome

My ajax request has cache set to false but Chrome still occasionally cache's it so when I hit the back button I get the cached data. I have tried adding a date/time/math random parameter to the end of the URL still without any luck. Is there any other way to make this never cache?

Thanks

Comment: `cache` affects the *request* that you're making...not the *result*, which is up to the browser.  When navigating back, no request is made at all...so that's out of jQuery's realm.  You'd have to trigger a re-request when navigating backwards...so a bit of a different problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure it is chrome that is doing the caching and not the webserver. from the looks of it you are doing the right thing to avoid caching. I would suggest setting the `cache-control` property in the header. depending on your server side scripting language find the right way to do the same.

JSP: `response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");`

PHP:

```
  <?php header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
  header("Pragma: no-cache");  `
```

Comment: Great `header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");` did it for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the cache to false adds a random parameter to the url, so you doing it yourself is repetitive.

The only reason this prevents caching is that it's never the same url twice.

Instead of expiring the ajax data, expire the page itself. When the page reloads it will automatically expire the data.

You can also try some events to the page to detect if it re-appears and clear the data.

PS. I HATE pages that do this, and I never come back to sites like that, so I hope you have a very targeted audience for this.